# How to pass authentication in React?

Tags: reactjs

Without some global state management library like [Redux](https://github.com/reactjs/redux), what would be a good way to pass the user around through my components?  I'm using [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/), so I'm imagining my top-level app component will be listening to auth changes and storing the user somewhere.  Here are the options I've thought of:

1. Passing 'user' to each route in props (and on to children that need it)
2. Using a global object of my own
3. Using [Context](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html)

1 seems like a hassle.

2 doesn't seem like the right way and like more of a hassle, wouldn't I have to listen for changes and set the user in my states?  It's what they show in the [React Router docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow) but I'm guessing that's just for simplicity's sake and not best practice.

3 seems like the best way to me but it seems like [it's discouraged](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html):

> The vast majority of applications do not need to use context.
>
> If you
>   want your application to be stable, don't use context. It is an
>   experimental API and it is likely to break in future releases of
>   React.

Answer (score 0):

I would still say that you use context. It's the best way I have found to thread a common state throughout the react tree.

Even though they discourage it, all popular react libraries (including react-redux) use it big time. It's not going to be removed any time soon. And the use case seems very legit, provided you know what you are doing.